# check for email domain in mysql doesn't work

Tags: mysql

i try to check the syntax of an email when inserting a new value,
but this doesn't seem to work :

```
create table foo (
    email varchar(100) not null,
    constraint foo_check1 check (email like '%@%.%')
);

insert into foo values ('bar'); /* OK ...why ? */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known limitation of MySQL - check constraints are not supported on `CREATE TABLE`.
See: "[The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html)"

You should create your table first, then alter it to add the check constraints.

Comment: thanks for this information, what would be the way to go though ?

Comment: i also tried to alter the table but it doesn't work, that is same result .

Comment: Seems MYSQL doesn't support check constraints at all.
You can emulate them with triggers however. See: http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Triggers#Emulating_Check_Constraints